# JS Task Runners without Extension (Mac User)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Good Afternoon fellow coders,

I've a small silly question, if someone could please clarify this for me. I came upon this extension which helps "Task runner for Grunt and Gulp directly within Visual Studio 2013."

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708

It seems to be only available for windows (Mac User), my question is; Can I just run my grunt/gulp through terminal instead of using an extension? Would it even work without conflicting?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure - Grunt and Gulp are nothing more than command line utilities - I work in visual studio and instead of using web essentials (which are still buggy for me) I just run gulp in cmd/terminal (linux at home, windows at work).

Plugin for VS is only a kind of visual sugar for gulp/grunt.

Comment: awesome buddy, i was just scared to try it out and mess up my production.
Thanks @user3560988